# Tizen watch app shows signing error when trying to install on Galaxy Watch

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am developing a web-based app on Tizen Studio 3.7 and I wish to install it on a Samsung Galaxy Watch. I am able to connect the watch to my PC via wifi, however, when I try to run the app I face the following error:
"
The application installation on the device has failed due to a signature error! (error code: -12)

You need an appropriate certificate profile, which can be created or activated in the Certificate Manager. Do you want to open the Certificate Manager?
"

I have run the same app a couple of months ago, and also I am currently using the same certificate profile as it was used earlier.
Also, the app runs fine on the emulator.

There are two more concerns related to my IDE, although not big, but those might be a associated with this issue.
-> the Certificate Manager never starts when I click on the button in Tizen Studio. I need to start it using eclipse.exe which is in \tools\certificate-manager .
-> also, the IDE never starts when I click on TizenStudio.exe, I need to start it using eclipse.exe which is in the same folder as TizenStudio.exe

I have tried creating new certificate profiles and building the app, yet the same error repeats.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and the reason was that I merely followed Samsung's tutorial, where this was not mentioned, so I had a Tizen certificate in the Certificate manager instead of a Samsung one.

If you also have a Tizen certificate in the manager, you should follow these steps:

1. Close Tizen Studio and all associated applications
2. Open the Tizen Studio Package manager
3. From the "Extension SDK" tab, install "Samsung Certificate Extension"
4. Open the Tizen Studio Certificate Manager
5. Remove your old certificate
6. Create a new certificate=>You should be able to choose Samsung from this window
   [image: List item]
7. Finish all the steps to create the certificate

Comment: Thank you for this solution of my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but got it resolved by generating a new certificate where only the DUID of my actual smartwatch was registered, not the one of the emulator.
After that everything worked out just fine, moreover it is still possible to run the app on the emulator.

(Also I can confirm the strange behaviour that the official `*.exe` files do not start the tools, but their corresponding `eclipse.exe` do.)

Answer (score 0):

How about you change the architecture of your project to arm instead of x86 from Project properties ? Then clean build, create new certificate and install in the watch. Please make sure the whole time your watch is connected and showing in the tizen studio.